# Ansible - loop over multiple items in stdout_lines

Tags: ansible

I am performing a grep with multiple items.

```yaml
---
- hosts: my_host
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    my_list:
      - whatever
      - something
  tasks:
    - name: grep for item in search path
      shell: "grep -rIL {{ item }} /tmp"
      register: the_grep
      loop: "{{ my_list }}"
    
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.stdout_lines }}"
      loop: "{{ the_grep.results }}"
```

Depending on the result, multiple files could match.

```
  msg:
  - /tmp/something.conf
  - /tmp/folder/file.txt
```

**Q**: How would I configure Ansible to loop over the items in `stdout_lines`?

The use case I'm solving is to delete .ini sections based on the item, but in this case, Ansible doesn't loop over the `stdout_lines`.

```yaml
- name: remove stanza from ini file
  ini_file:
    path: "{{ item.stdout_lines }}"
    section: "{{ item.item }}"
    mode: '0600'
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ the_grep.results }}"
  when: item.stdout_lines | length > 0
```

It seems that this doesn't work, but configuring `item.stdout_lines[0]` gives the *partially* expected result, since Ansible will use only the first item in that list. But ofc, not the 2nd and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there's a prettier answer, but solved it by using `with_nested` and creating a `json_query`:

```yaml
- name: remove stanza from ini file
  ini_file:
    path: "{{ item.0 }}"
    section: "{{ item.1.item }}"
    mode: '0600'
    state: absent
  with_nested: 
    - "{{ the_grep | json_query('results[].stdout_lines[]') }}"
    - "{{ the_grep.results }}"
```